# MYSQL - Login verification with two separate tables without any links

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables - 'users' and 'staffs'. 'users' contains the login information for the public wears while 'staffs' contains the login information for the administrators. In my login page, both users and staffs are able to login through the same webpage. For the login verification, how should I write my SQLquery so that it can retrieve users(email, user_password) and staffs(staffmail, password) to verify?

My current SQL codes are:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name from users
union all
SELECT staffname, staffrole from staffs
WHERE email = 'glenn@hotmail.com' and user_password = '112'
OR staffmail ='joe@aventis.edu.sg' and password = 'joe123'
```

However, this will not be able to generate any outputs.

Comment: Can you make it simple like this: check in `users` table if any rows available for given email, if exists validate password, otherwise go with `staffs`. Remember to use some password hash and salt to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Why can't you use same tables for both users and staffs and distinguish with the role column?

Comment: One solution is to pass another field from the login form that whether a user or admin trying to login.

Comment: Second solution: First query on the user table if it fail try to query on the second table.

Comment: @MyWay , I agree with you. If I write this with PHP, must I use an IF ELSE statement, or is there a away for me to write it in a single SQL query?

Comment: @Pradeepta is there a way to write this in a single SQL query?

Comment: No i have not done that.Its better to store the login detail on the users table with a type column , and the detail for users in user_details and staff_details for staff.

Answer (score 0):

try with this queries..

```
SELECT 'users',first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE email = 'glenn@hotmail.com' AND user_password = '112'
union all
SELECT 'staffs', staffname, staffrole FROM staffs WHERE email ='glenn@hotmail.com' AND user_password = '112'
```

here first column returns where the entry is..

Comment: hi, I forgot to state that both the login fields for each tables are different -
users (email & user_password) and staffs (staffmail & password)

Comment: yes alternate the column name accordingly, or use same table for both type of users and make a column to save the role as sanjay said